# How to send Templates to multiple Recruiter by Email from DocuSign in PHP

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign REST API to send documents for signature and am having trouble sending to multiple recipients.  If I send to just one recipient it works fine, but I can't send to multiple recipients.  I'm using the following PHP for single and multiple recipients:

```
$data = array(
  "accountId" => $accountId,
  "emailSubject" => "abc",
  "emailBlurb" => "These are the completed documents for $email",
  "templateId" => $templateId,
  "templateRoles" => array(
    array(
      "email" => $email,
      "name" => $name,
      "roleName" => "Signer",
      "clientUserId" => $clientUserId,
    ),
    array(
      "email" => 'some@gmail.com',
      "name" => 'xxxxx',
      "roleName" => "Recruiter",
      "clientUserId" => NULL,
    ),
  ),
  "status" => "sent"
);
```

Here I'm trying like below:

```
 $data = array(
  "accountId" => $accountId,
  "emailSubject" => "abc",
  "emailBlurb" => "These are the completed documents for $email",
  "templateId" => $templateId,
  "templateRoles" => array(
    array(
      "email" => $email,
      "name" => $name,
      "roleName" => "Signer",
      "clientUserId" => $clientUserId,
    ),
    array(
      "email" => 'some1@gmail.com',
      "name" => 'xxxxx',
      "roleName" => "Recruiter",
      "clientUserId" => NULL,
    ),
    array(
      "email" => 'some2@gmail.com',
      "name" => 'xxxxx',
      "roleName" => "Recruiter",
      "clientUserId" => NULL,
    ),`enter code here`
    array(
      "email" => 'some3@gmail.com',
      "name" => 'xxxxx',
      "roleName" => "Recruiter",
      "clientUserId" => NULL,
    ),
  ),
  "status" => "sent"
);
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem**.

Comment: So what error do you get when you try to send to multiple recipients?  Or is there no error but the recipients don't receive the notification emails?

Comment: And which API call are you using?  Please list the URL/endpoint that you are hitting...

Comment: working Funny, If I'm adding one recruiter mail there then it is sending by attaching the filled templates. But if I'm adding two or more recruiter mails then also sending mail but not attaching templates.

Comment: One more thing is that, when adding multiple recruiter mails there, It is sending mail before candidate filled template.

Comment: In The flow of my website The candidate should fill the templates and After finishing when he click on confirm I should send those templates to recruiters. That is my plan?

Answer (score 0):

When sending electronic signature requests through the DocuSign api there are two main methods of initiating the requests for your recipients- **Remote** or **Embedded** (aka **Captive**).

- Remote recipients receive an *email* notifying them that a document requires their signature.
- Embedded or Captive recipients can open the envelope directly by navigating to a URL.

The steps for adding each of these recipients to your envelopes are exactly the same EXCEPT that for Remote recipients you do NOT set the `clientUserId` property at all (i.e. no reference to that property at all in the request) and for Embedded recipients you add the `clientUserId` property and give it a value.

If you are not accessing the envelopes by generating URL tokens, and it sounds like you are not, then remove the `clientUserId` property from those recipients and it should work.

The [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) has all the info you need on this and more, see the Features section under Explore.

Comment: In The flow of my website The candidate should fill the templates and After finishing when he click on confirm I should send those templates to recruiters. That is my plan?